# TK to run django server on windows

Tags: python, django, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have windows server running Django as a CMD process.

Some PC USERS mistakenly closing it.

I want to switch to TK running the Django server and put output on screen.

How safe is that ?

How do I close the django properly ?

```
class TextRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.see(tk.END)
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")


class TkApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        # set window size
        self.geometry("500x200")
        self.title("DJANGO")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.tag_configure("stderr", foreground="#b22222")
        self.text.yview("end")
        self.iconbitmap("activity.ico")
        sys.stdout = TextRedirector(self.text, "stdout")
        sys.stderr = TextRedirector(self.text, "stderr")

        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_close)

        self.run()

    def on_close(self):
        response = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Exit', 'Are you sure you want to exit?')
        if response:
            try:
                # KILL THE DJANGO PROCESS
                ....
            finally:
                sys.exit(0)

    def run(self):
        # RUN THE DJANGO PROCESS
        ....



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TkApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

will this work ?
I also need to tell the django to close nicely (same as I would click the X button on command line)
Instead:
[image]

I want:
[image]

For some reason it opens the command line for the django (tested with ping) an not redirect the text.
[image]

**SOLUTION:**
I was not able to redirect the process out put instead I run django main() from a thread. is it risky ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import traceback
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END
import tkinter.messagebox


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'main.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


class TextRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.see(tk.END)
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")


class TkApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        toolbar = tk.Frame(self)
        toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        # set window size
        self.geometry("500x200")
        self.title("DJANGO")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="word")
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.tag_configure("stderr", foreground="#b22222")
        self.text.yview("end")
        self.iconbitmap("activity.ico")
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.on_close)
        self.django_thread = None
        self.event = None
        sys.stdout = TextRedirector(self.text, "stdout")
        sys.stderr = TextRedirector(self.text, "stderr")

        self.run()

    def on_close(self):
        response = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Exit', 'Are you sure you want to exit?')
        if response:
            try:
                # STOP THE DJANGO PROCESS
                # stop the thread
                self.event.set()
                # wait for the new thread to stop
                self.django_thread.join()
                self.destroy()
            finally:
                print('[on_close] Done')

    def run(self):
        self.process = threading.Thread(target=main)
        self.process.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = TkApp()
    app.mainloop()
```